# How can I write object oriented Javascript without using a framework?

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I am still trying to teach myself Javascript and I was wondering whether someone knew the best way to write object oriented Javascript with classes that will interact well with PHP classes.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes, it uses a prototype-based inheritance model. There are ways of making it simulate more class-based models, but I don't think it's worth the effort. "Object oriented" can be a pretty vague term - is there a specific problem you're trying to solve with classes?

Comment: @nnnnnn A+ I agree, what is the problem involved that requires classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is already object oriented, in regards to classes there are many ways in which to achieve "templates". Since you are new to Javascript have a good read of any material from [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/) especially his book **The Good Parts** as he will enlighten you to the the true nature of Javascsript.

This leads me to the second part of your question, as to interacting well with PHP, my advice (from experience) is to have a good clear data serialization/deserialization layer from which you interact, [JSON](http://www.json.org/) will help you immensely. Don't try and be clever, Javascript is a very **different** language to PHP. Work with the language not against it.

Happy coding :)

Comment: After you read the book, you should study some existing frameworks to consolidate your knowledges.

Comment: @dnikku I agree (somewhat), since it is implied that willpots is getting into web development then **jQuery** (library) is a **MUST** :)

Comment: @martin - I think jQuery is great and I use it a lot, but "a must"? Hardly. There are lots of other options.

Comment: @nnnnnn I know there are plenty of other alternatives (many which have evolved more and more like jQuery); however especially for a beginner the sheer size of the community makes it more than worthwhile getting to grips with - but maybe I'm a little biased :)

Comment: See, I did it wrong. I learned jQuery to begin with but I am realizing that for some applications, it can be easier to write scratch Javascript. Maybe I'm crazy though :)

Comment: @willpots Have you tried writing any custom plugins, I have found it lends itself to very structured code.

Comment: No, I haven't although I have used many. I will look into it. Thanks.